# EC2 non root user login

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to log into an EC2 ubuntu ami or a way to set up an ubuntu ami so that non-root users can log in?  I tried creating a user and logging in with the associated password.  I also tried using the private key, copied the authorized-keys file into the .ssh directory of the non-root user's home directory and tried to log in to the box with that user account id.  Neither method worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are sending your AWS keypair as the identity file, i.e.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/keypair.pem user@ec2-174-129-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Also check that SSH is enabled in your security group

Comment: This was basically what I did at first, but your comment reminded me that I did not set the permissions on the authorized-keys file correctly.

Answer (score 5):

So, this works, but the missing high-order bit of information here has to do with setting the right permission on the authorized-keys file in the home directory for the user. So, I copied /root/.ssh/authorized-key to /home/user, then did with

```
cp -r /root/.ssh /home/user

chown -R user /home/user/.ssh
```

This allowed me to use the keypair.pem file to log in.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you would like to have users log in with a password so they need not supply a key every time, all you must do is turn on the ability to SSH in with a password.  This option is turned off by default in all Linux AMIs.

vi, nano, pico, etc. into the following file with root privileges:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssg/sshd_config
```

Change the following setting to yes:

```
PasswordAuthentication = yes
```

Finally you must restart SSH (Since you are SSHed onto a remote machine, a simple reboot is fine.)

That's it!  Of course, you must still add users with the `adduser` command and give them passwords with the `passwd` command for them to be able to login to your AMI.  Checkout this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/ssh_config.5.html) for more info on the OpenSSH SSH client configuration files.